# understanding why $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$ has only one subgroup of size $8$

Tags: group-theory

How do I prove that $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$ has one subgroup of size $8$? Similarly, How do I prove that $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$ has one subgroup of size $8$?

My thoughts so far:

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$ has subgroup $ \mathbb{Z}_8\times\{0\}$. I also know that any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$ must be abelian. I have a theorem in my book(fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups) that tells me that, because the subgroup is of size 8 and abelian, it must be isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}_8$ or $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Now, $ \mathbb{Z}_8\times\{0\} \cong \mathbb{Z}_8$. But how can I show that  $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$ has no subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. How can I show that  $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_9$ does not have two different subgroups ismorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_8$?

Comment: Because $\mathbb Z_9$ has no subgroup of order $2$.

Comment: Right, because of Lagrange thm, but after this comment I am still not understanding.

Comment: Because if it were the case $\{0\}\times\Bbb{Z}_2$ would be isomorphic to a subgroup of order $2$ of $\Bbb{Z}_9$

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any element $(a,b)\in \Bbb Z_8\times\Bbb Z_9$ with $b\neq0$. What do you know about the order of $(a,b)$? Can it be an element of an order 8 subgroup?

Comment: I know that the order of (a,b) is the LCM(a/gcd(8,a),b/gcd(9,b)). But what am I to do with this?

Comment: @gewDog5 Just list them all. What are the possible values for that order?

Comment: So the cyclic subgroups generated by $(a,b)$ when $b \not = 0$ must be a multiple of $3$. So $3$ must divide the order of any subgroup that contains $(a,b)$, therefore no subgroup is of size $8$. Is this the reasoning you are trying to lead me to?

Comment: @gewbDog5 That's exactly the reasoning I was trying to lead you to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is useful general property: if $H$ and $K$ are finite groups of *relatively prime* orders then every subgroup of $H \times K$ has the form $A \times B$ where $A$ is a subgroup of $H$ and $B$ is a subgroup of $K$.

In particular, the only subgroup of $H \times K$ of order $|H|$ is $H \times \{1\}$.  That answers the question you are asking.

The above property is false if $|H|$ and $|K|$ have a common factor greater than 1. For example, supposing $H = K$, inside $H \times H$ we have the diagonal subgroup $\Delta = \{(h,h) : h \in H\}$ and this is not of the form $A \times B$ for subgroups $A$ and $B$ of $H$ when $H$ is nontrivial.